# Draw a circle at coordines computed using some \def variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying to draw a circle at some specific coordinates defined by some simple arithmetic calculations. The reason why I am trying to do so is that eventually I would like to change the inclination of the line and compute some intersections with the background grid. Specifically I would like to draw a circle at the mid point of each segment form between the line and the background grid.

I have made the simplest possible example to reproduce the issue.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{tikz}

% .... remarks
% \theoremstyle{remark} 
% \newtheorem{remark}{\bf Remark}
\newtheorem{testcase}{\bf Test case}

% .... bar charts and plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}                    
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Ax{0}
\def\Ay{0}
\def\Bx{20}
\def\By{20}

% mx + q
\def\Dy{\By - \Ay}
\def\Dx{\Bx - \Ax}
\def\m{(\Dy) / (\Dx) }
\def\q{\Ay -  \m*\Ax  }


\draw[black, step=4] (0,0) grid + (20,20);
\draw[very thick, black] (\Ax, \Ay) to  (\Bx, \By);

\def\ax{5}
\def\ay{\m * \ax + \q}
\draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] (\ax, \ay) circle (0.15);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I do not understand why I receive a compilation error relative to how the coordinates of the node.

The error is the following:

> Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. \draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] (\ax, \ay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\def`.  Everything is going to be run through `\pgfmathparse` eventually (automatically), so calculate it now instead of later.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{tikz}

% .... remarks
% \theoremstyle{remark} 
% \newtheorem{remark}{\bf Remark}
\newtheorem{testcase}{\bf Test case}

% .... bar charts and plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}                    
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Ax{0}
\def\Ay{0}
\def\Bx{20}
\def\By{20}

% mx + q
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Dy}{\By - \Ay}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Dx}{\Bx - \Ax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\Dy / \Dx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\q}{\Ay -  \m*\Ax}


\draw[black, step=4] (0,0) grid + (20,20);
\draw[very thick, black] (\Ax, \Ay) to  (\Bx, \By);

\def\ax{5}
\def\ay{\m * \ax + \q}
\draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] (\ax, \ay) circle (0.15);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with Andrew that these `\def`s are not necessarily good practice, I regret (and I really mean regret) to disagree with the main statement that Ti*k*Z isn't able to parse these. It absolutely is. You only need to add braces since otherwise the parser gets confused by the parentheses. (Internally the pgf keys are also just macros, so obviously Ti*k*Z is able to parse macros.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Ax{0}
\def\Ay{0}
\def\Bx{20}
\def\By{20}

% mx + q
\def\Dy{\By - \Ay}
\def\Dx{\Bx - \Ax}
\def\m{(\Dy) / (\Dx) }
\def\q{\Ay -  \m*\Ax  }
\draw[black, step=4] (0,0) grid + (20,20);
\draw[very thick, black] ({\Ax}, {\Ay}) to  ({\Bx}, {\By});
\def\ax{5}
\def\ay{\m * \ax + \q}
\draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] ({\ax},{\ay}) circle (0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With regards to best practices, like Andrew I do like pgf keys a lot, but one can also just `declare function`s. (A constant is a valid function, too.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Ax=0;Ay=0;Bx=20;By=20;
    Dy=By-Ay;Dx=Bx-Ax;m=Dy/Dx;q=Ay-m*Ax;ax=5;ay=m*ax+q;}]
\draw[black, step=4] (0,0) grid + (20,20);
\draw[very thick, black] (Ax, Ay) to  (Bx,By);
\draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] (ax,ay) circle[radius=0.15];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I like `declare function`.

Comment: +1  Very nice! I need to read up on how these functions work.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that `tikz` is not able to work with the expressions that `\ax` and `\ay` expand to. [*Actually, this is not quite right. See Schrödinger's cat's answer.*] For example, you have:

> ay=0-20/20-0+5+20-0-20/20-0*0

What you need to do is force these expressions to be evaluated. I recommend using `pgfkeys` to store and process your variables. To set this up looks like a mouthful when you first see it, but the syntax is not so complicated once you have read through it.

```
\newcommand\Var[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Variables/#1}}
\newcommand\SetVar[1]{\pgfkeys{/Variables, #1, Calc}}
\tikzset{/Variables/.is family, /Variables,
  Ax/.initial=0,
  Ay/.initial=0,
  Bx/.initial=20,
  By/.initial=20,
  Dx/.initial=20,
  Dy/.initial=20,
  ax/.initial=5,
  ay/.initial=5,
  m/.initial=1,
  q/.initial=0,
  Calc/.style = {
      Dx=\the\numexpr\Var{Bx}-\Var{Ax}\relax,
      Dy=\the\numexpr\Var{By}-\Var{Ay}\relax,
      m=\the\numexpr\Var{Dy}/\Var{Dx}\relax,
      q=\the\numexpr\Var{Ay}-\Var{m}*\Var{Ax}\relax,
      ay=\the\numexpr\Var{m}+\Var{ax}+\Var{q}\relax
  }
}
```

From the point of view of your problem the most important point is the use of `\numexpr` to evaluate the expressions. What the rest of the code does is, first, initialise the variables `Ax`,`Ay`, `Bx`, `By`, `Dx`, `Dy`, `ax`, `ay`, `m` and `q` and it defines a `Calc` method that calculates `Dx`, `Dy`, `m` and `q` from the current values of `Ax`,`Ay`, `Bx`, `By`, `ax` and`ay`. Finally, there are two helper macros, `\Var` for accessing the current values of the variables and `\SetVar` for setting new values -- and automatically applying `Calc` to recalulate the remaining values.

Putting this together the code below produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{tikz}

% .... remarks
% \theoremstyle{remark}
% \newtheorem{remark}{\bf Remark}
\newtheorem{testcase}{\bf Test case}

% .... bar charts and plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand\Var[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Variables/#1}}
\newcommand\SetVar[1]{\pgfkeys{/Variables, #1, Calc}}
\tikzset{/Variables/.is family, /Variables,
  Ax/.initial=0,
  Ay/.initial=0,
  Bx/.initial=20,
  By/.initial=20,
  Dx/.initial=20,
  Dy/.initial=20,
  ax/.initial=5,
  ay/.initial=5,
  m/.initial=1,
  q/.initial=0,
  Calc/.style = {
      Dx=\the\numexpr\Var{Bx}-\Var{Ax}\relax,
      Dy=\the\numexpr\Var{By}-\Var{Ay}\relax,
      m=\the\numexpr\Var{Dy}/\Var{Dx}\relax,
      q=\the\numexpr\Var{Ay}-\Var{m}*\Var{Ax}\relax,
      ay=\the\numexpr\Var{m}+\Var{ax}+\Var{q}\relax
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[black, step=4] (0,0) grid + (20,20);

    % default
    \draw[very thick, black] (\Var{Ax}, \Var{Ay}) to  (\Var{Bx}, \Var{By});
    \draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] (\Var{ax}, \Var{ay}) circle (0.15);

    \SetVar{Ax=4,Ay=16, Bx=16, By=4}
    \draw[very thick, black] (\Var{Ax}, \Var{Ay}) to  (\Var{Bx}, \Var{By});
    \draw[thin, blue, fill = blue] (\Var{ax}, \Var{ay}) circle (0.15);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure that I understand where you want the blue dots but both dots are in accordance with your calculations.